# Regex for tickers on stock and crypto market

Tags: node.js, regex

I am struggling to create a functional regex with the following criteria:

- Identify a MAX of 5 lowercase characters ONLY after a '$' sign and before a space OR at the end of a sentence (empty string or peroid '.')
- AND match a MAX of 5 UPPERCASE letters with OR without a '$' sign at the front that HAVE to be followed by a space, symbol (comma, exclamation) or be at the end of a sentence (empty string or peroid '.')
- If there is a match of any kind

Examples of matches

"The $APPL fell on the TSLA." (should match $APPL and TSLA)
"$gme is an APEs game" (should only match $gme)
"This a game of $money. Where LAMBO" (should match $money and LAMBO)

I have been playing with the following, getting some parts to work but never all in one:

```
const found = [
    "this is an APPL",
    "this is an APPL.",
    "this is an $APPL",
    "this is an $appl",
    "this is an $appl.",
    "this is an $appl and orange.",
    "this is an $appl, and orange.",
    "this is an $APPL and orange.",
    "this is an $APPL, and orange.",
    "this is an APPL! and orange."
];

const notFound = [
    "this is an appl.",
    "this is an $applasdfasdf.",
    "this is an APPLLLLLL",
    "this is an $APPLLLLLL"
];

const matchTicker = /[$][A-Za-z]{0,5}/;

// Should evaluate to TRUE
console.log("\nFOUND\n");
found.forEach((ticker) => {
    console.log(matchTicker.test(ticker));
});

// Should evaluate to FALSE
console.log("\nNOT FOUND\n");
notFound.forEach((ticker) => {
    console.log(matchTicker.test(ticker));
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this work for you:

```bash
\$[a-z]{2,5}\b|\$?\b[A-Z]{2,5}\b
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gNXlB6/1)

**RegEx Explanation:**

- `\$[a-z]{2,5}\b`: first case with lowercase letters
- `|`: or
- `\$?\b[A-Z]{2,5}\b`: second case with uppercase letters

Comment: Oooo, almost, the only thing it isn't matching is if it is followed by a symbol: `$appl, blah` for instance. Or: `AAPL! blah`

Comment: Strange, normally these should match too, see [RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/v6XBto/1).

Comment: Ah, that was my mistake. Thank you Alex.